# lastChild.remove() doesn't work on IE

Tags: javascript, html

I want to dynamically add and remove input files, my code works great on all browsers without Internet Explorer. Can anyone help me to resolve my problem?
Here is the Javascript:

```
<script>
            var counter = 1;
            var min = 1;
            var max = 20;
            function addInput(divName) {
                if (counter == max) {
                    alert("Max limit!");
                }
                else {
                    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
                    newdiv.innerHTML = '<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file"><br>';
                    document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
                    document.getElementById("qty").value++;
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            function remInput(divName) {
                if (counter == min) {
                    alert("Min limit!");
                }
                else {
                    var element = document.getElementById(divName);
                    element.lastChild.remove();
                    document.getElementById("qty").value--;
                    counter--;
                }
            }
        </script>
```

And here is the HTML code:

```
<input type="button" value="-" onClick="remInput('plus');">
<input type="text" name="qty" id='qty' size='2' style="text-align: center" disabled value="1">
<input type="button" value="+" onClick="addInput('plus');">

   <div id="plus">
       <input type="file" name="file[]" id="file"><br>
   </div>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its seems that remove() is not supported in IE, do add condition in your code, if particular function is supported in your browser(in this case remove() function)

Please refer below working add.

```
<script>
 var counter = 1;
            var min = 1;
            var max = 20;
            function addInput(divName) {
                if (counter == max) {
                    alert("Max limit!");
                }
                else {
                    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
                    var inputid="file"+counter;
                    newdiv.innerHTML = '<input type="file" name="file[]" id='+inputid+'><br>';
                    document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
                    document.getElementById("qty").value++;
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            function remInput(divName) {
                if (counter == min) {
                    alert("Min limit!");
                }
                else {
                    var element = document.getElementById(divName);
                    if(element.lastChild.remove!= undefined)
                    element.lastChild.remove();
                    else
                    element.lastChild.parentNode.removeChild(element.lastChild);
                    document.getElementById("qty").value--;
                    counter--;
                }
            }


</script>
```